# vuejs component inside legacy rails modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I want to implement a vuejs component inside an existing bootstrap slim modal.

In the modal I reference the container of the component like usually:

```
form.slim
= modal do
  = javascript_pack_tag 'product_asset', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  #product_assets[
    data-product-asset-routes=JsRoutes.generate(include: /product_asset/)
  ]
end
```

Outside of a modal it works properly. But in this action it doesn't.
The console output shows this:

```
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: null
Source Map URL: product_asset-ed5ee8937047520ba766.js.map
```

Anyone of you handled with this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

I expected an event to fire. Something like turbolinks:load. But this is an XHR-Request where this kind of stuff doesnt happen.

From:

```
document.addEventListener(turbolinks:load => ({
  const productAsset = new Vue({
    el: '#product_asset_form',
    store,
    railsI18n,
    productAssetRoutes,
    render: h => h(ProductAsset, { props: { ...root_element.dataset } }),
  }).$mount()
)}
```

To:

```
const productAsset = new Vue({
  el: '#product_asset_form',
  store,
  // this is vue-i18n magic...
  i18n: railsI18n,
  productAssetRoutes,
  render: h => h(ProductAsset, { props: { ...root_element.dataset } }),
}).$mount()
```

And now it fires immediatly